# SpringBoot : RestAPI Returning JSON Array But I want value with label to set in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, rest

**Requirement:** 
Trying to populate all UNIQUE record in Angular Drop Down List

I am using predefined Table have already data.

REST API URL =>  http://localhost:8080/getAllCategory

**Facing Problem:**

API is giving the reponse in JSON Array like [xxx,yyyy,zzzz]. So I am thinking if I can convert JSON Array with some label value which can solve my problem.

Either any other way to get over with this issue.

Note :

```
 If I am not using the native query and using the below code then I am getting all the table value in JSON with label and populating all the record in drop down but I want only UNIQUE
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ccCategory,Integer>
{}
```

**My Implementation :**

**Model :**

```
@Table(name = "cccategory")
    public class ccCategory 
    {   
        @Id
        @Column(name = "[catid]")
        public Integer catID;

        @Column(name = "[categoryname]")
        public String categoryName;


        @Column(name = "[active]")
        public int active;

        public ccCategory() {
        }



        public String getCategoryName() {
            return categoryName;
        }

        public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
            this.categoryName = categoryName;
        }




        public int getActive() {
            return active;
        }

        public void setActive(int active) {
            this.active = active;
        }

    }
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ccCategory,Integer>
{

    public static final String FIND_CATEGORYNAME = "SELECT DISTINCT catID,categoryName from ccCategory";

    @Query(value = FIND_CATEGORYNAME, nativeQuery = true)
    List<ccCategory> getByactive(int active);
}
```

**Controller :**

```
   @GetMapping("/getAllCategory")
        public List<Object> getAllCategory() {
        // public List<ccCategory> getAllCategory() {
        System.out.println("***** Call : API getAllCategory() ******");

        List<Object> cCategory = categoryRepository.getCategoryName();

            return categoryData;
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all records?

Comment: No, I want to retrieve the UNIQUE record and want to populate it in Angular dropdown list.  But  In my case I am getting unique record  JSON array like [xxx,yyy,zzzz]  is any way to add a label in this data to it help me to retrieve..